# Unity: Create a custom editor for Vector2

Tags: unity, c#

I'm starting to dig into Unity's editor customization. What I'm looking for is a way to create custom line (or a point at least) which I could move around in SceneView and set a Vector2 value that way.

[image: Picture might explain it somewhat better]

I might create a child GameObject and then calculate the relative distance, but I'd like to know, if there is any way using the Editor instead of adding other useless GameObjects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer just now, but to get you started: Unity uses the [Handles class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) to draw & use its interactive widgets in the scene. You can use these by writing a custom editor for your class with an OnSceneGUI method.

Comment: *offtopic:* Whoa, a vector creator? I want this!

Comment: Just checking: what you are trying to achieve is a visualization of a vector? Displaying it as a gizmo-line works for you?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I would like to get. Instead of hard-coding the vector myself it would be much easier if I could easily see another "transform" (drawing the vector shouldn't  be a huge problem) in the SceneView and be able to edit it. I've looked at the Handles but I haven't really found the solution yet.